# Enable nvidia modesetting after boot

Tags: nvidia, kernel

There is a conflict in my system between PCI passthrough and nvidia modesetting. if both are enabled at boot, then the boot fails.
I would like to set the kernel parameter **nvidia-drm.modeset=1** after boot.Without that I cannot have wayland support.
The sysctl command is not applicable. I get the following error:

> sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/nvidia-drm/modeset: No such file or
> directory

Comment: What is the full line of text at `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` please? You can see this by typing `cat /etc/default/grub` in your terminal.

Comment: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intel_iommu=on video=vesafb:off,efifb:off mitigations=off init_on_alloc=0 kvm.ignore_msrs=1"

Comment: Do you know how to edit grub at boot? That way you can test without making permanent changes. Try replacing your _DEFAULT= with `rhgb quiet splash acpi_enforce_resources=lax pcie_ports=compat` and let us know. I think that modding the kernel might be a bit extreme unless you find a guru, so try changing some of these paramaters.

Comment: I can boot with ether parameter "intel_iommu=on" or with "nvidia-drm.modeset=1", but not with both (editing /etc/default/grub appropriately). If it makes a difference. I have the MSI x299 MB and intel i9-9800x cpu. I do not have this issue with my AMD computer.

Comment: I can see how this can be frustrating, when you have a sweet graphics card and Ubuntu doesn't want to play with it. If you `dmesg` and search theat big dump, do you find any specific errors relating to the graphics card or PCI ?

Answer (score 2):

ello! Bit late but what can you do :p The basic thing you need to run in the command line to enable modesetting after boot is:

modprobe -r nvidia_drm ; modprobe nvidia_drm modeset=1

For more information see the [nvidia XFree86 page](https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/515.57/README/kms.html), please note that in time whats written on the page may change so update the url based on what your nvidia driver version is!

Comment: Somehow the link you tried to put in the answer failed to actually end up in the answer - you might want to fix that.

Comment: @ArrayBolt3 Ah! Thanks for noting it!

Comment: Thanks, Late is better than not at all.